# How to set border-spacing=0

Tags: css, css-tables, border-spacing

I have to set `border-spacing:0` with `border:0` in CSS of table.

Adding `border-collapse:collapse` and `border:0` did not work.
Neither adding `border-collapse:separate` under `border:0` and simply the removal of border or border-spacing property under `border-collapse:collapse` did not work in CSS.

As clicking <kbd>F12</kbd> function key in Chrome, I noticed that border-spacing of table element remains 2px and never change regardless of border width and border-collapse.

Is there anyway to solve this issue without changing codes from table structure to others?

Comment: You didn't write "I have tried `border-spacing:0`", so I was wondering...

Comment: As one can't set `border-spacing:0` with `border:0` in CSS of table, you might want to explain, together with a code sample, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: can you reproducable issue as working snippet. we can changes relatively what you need